# Should I take-off and wear again the ihram when want to perform another umrah

Tags: sharia, sunni, umrah

For repeated Umrah, should I take off my first Ahram after completion of first Umrah and wear it again from Meeqat Masjid Aisha, or keep on wearing the same and make Niyyah for next Umrah?

Comment: It is discouraged to do two umrahs in a single journey. Perform tawaf instead

Answer (score 1):

You can make your repeated Umrah using the same cloth [2] but to catch the sunnah you should take shower [1] and differently you have to take off your cloth. But you don't want to do that so only make Niyyah.

1. http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=159221
2. https://www.binbaz.org.sa/noor/9971

I hope my answer is helpful for you.

Mohammad

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your initial *Niyyah*. If you were intended to perform more than one *Umrahs* with same *Ihram* i.e. you have a composite *Niyyah* then its okay but if you intended to perform each *Umrah* solely then put off the *Ihram* and re-wear it for the other.

Comment: Please consider adding references to support your claims!